# File permissions issue with an NFSv4 share, uploaded from a Mac Lion

Tags: osx-lion, file-permissions, nfs, acl

I have an NFSv4 share that was working fine, with Macs using Snow Leopard, to share files across the network. The NFS share has one cloned user/group that all clients autoconnect as. All files uploaded to the share have the cloned user and group as their owner/group.

However, when I use a Lion Mac to copy a file from their user directory to the NFS, no other computer (mac SL/mac Lion/Win7) can edit/delete/write to the file that was uploaded - despite having the correct read/write/ex permissions visible on the NFS and through terminal. Attempting to edit the file permissions through Finder completely locks the file.

I suspect this has something to do with Lion's ACLs (or maybe its version control) conflicting with NFSv4.

Is there a way to disable or ignore extended ACLs or extended file permissions on the NFSv4 side, that would allow users to not run into this conflict?

The work around currently is to use NFS Manager and set automounts to ignore ownership but installing NFS manager and configuring automounts for all of the computers seems more troubling than attempting to reconfigure the NFS settings.

Advice?